# Plotting .xyz points on a map

Tags: python

I have a script that prints out a Mexico map with data on it and I need to add thousands of points to the map. I have all the points in an .xyz file (long, lat, point #) and I assume there is a pretty straight forward way to do this, but I have not been able to figure it out. I have converted this .xyz file to a .csv file, assuming this would be necessary.

Here is a short excerpt from the .xyz file.

```
-103.4855194092,25.5515251160,3
-103.4993667603,25.5775527954,4
-103.5101470947,25.6047039032,5
-103.5209426880,25.6318778992,6
-103.5317306519,25.6590518951,7
-103.5425415039,25.6862201691,8
-103.5533523560,25.7133903503,9
-103.5641708374,25.7405548096,10
```

Here is the script (day1.py) that prints out the Mexico map with my data on it.

```
#!\usr\bin\env python

from mexico import *
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy
import time
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

# use low resolution coastlines.
# don't plot features that are smaller than 2000 square km.

map = Basemap(width=2800000, height=2200000, projection='lcc', resolution='l', area_thresh=2000, lat_1=45, lat_2=55, lat_0=25, lon_0=-103)

#map.bluemarble()
# draw coastlines, country boundaries, fill continents.
map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)
map.drawcountries(linewidth=0.5)
map.drawstates(linewidth=0.5)
map.fillcontinents(color = 'white')

# draw the edge of the map projection region (the projection limb)
map.drawmapboundary()

date = datetime.now()
date1 = date + timedelta(days=1)

for c in cities :
        c.retrieveTemps()
        long, lat = c.long, c.lat
        x, y = map(float(long), float(lat))
        if int(c.high0) >= 34:
                plt.text(x, y, int(c.high0), fontsize=7, fontweight='bold')
        if int(c.low0) <=3:
                plt.text(x, y, int(c.low0), fontsize=7, fontweight='bold')
        plt.title('Period 1: %s Critical Temperatures' % date1.strftime('%A'), fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')

plt.show()
```

So within this script I need to add in something to plot all the points in the .xyz file. Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: What data type is `cities`?  I assume it's list of something.  I also assume the points you're plotting currently are different than the points in your .xyz file?

Comment: cities pulls a string out of an html file and is completely unrelated to the .xyz file. I can convert the .xyz file to a shape file or pretty much anything else if that makes it easier.